# How to Implement Dashed Progress Bar with units wise increase in android

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-custom-view, seekbar

I want this type of view, I checked Discrete Seekbar but it is showing dots for each step even Thumb and Track are changed.
[image: Low to High meter]

If I use Seekbar with custom Thumb and Progress Drawable, I was unable to set Progress properly on the Dotted line attached using ProgressDrawable and how to restrict the user to drag Seekbar.

```
<!-- dotted.xml -->
<layer-list
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:android1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!--Item background and progress order cannot be reversed-->
<item android:id= "@android:id/background" >
    <shape android:shape= "line" >
        <stroke
            android:width= "10dp"
            android:color= "#E9EAF5"
        android:dashWidth="10dp" android:dashGap="4dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>

<SeekBar
android:id="@+id/seekBar"
android:layout_width="181dp"
android:layout_height="48dp"
android:enabled="false"
android:progress="6"
android:progressDrawable="@drawable/dotted"
android:thumb="@drawable/circle_progress" />
```

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?